What is the difference between "JVM thread_state" and "java.lang.Thread.State" in a thread dump?
In below thread dump, there seems to be two different thread states: JVM thread_state and java.lang.Thread.State. Which one is the actual state of the thread?
JVM thread_state is "_thread_blocked", while java.lang.Thread.State is "TIMED_WAITING":
“Test” #867 daemon prio = 5 os_prio = 0 tid = 0x820009600000 nid =
    0x1260e7 [JVM thread_state = _thread_blocked,
              locked by VM(w / poll advisory bit)
                  waiting on VM lock 'self_suspend_monitor for TID 1204455',
              polling bits:safep] java.lang.Thread
            .State : TIMED_WAITING(parking)
                         at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method) -
        locked<0x000002000507d440>(
            a org.jctools.queues.MpscBlockingConsumerArrayQueue)
            at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport
                .parkNanos(LockSupport.java : 215)
                    at org.jctools.queues.MpscBlockingConsumerArrayQueue
                .parkUntilNext(MpscBlockingConsumerArrayQueue.java : 536)
                    at org.jctools.queues.MpscBlockingConsumerArrayQueue
                .poll(MpscBlockingConsumerArrayQueue.java : 512)
                    at datadog.trace.agent.common.writer
                .TraceProcessingWorker$TraceSerializingHandler
                .consumeFromPrimaryQueue(TraceProcessingWorker.java : 254)
                    at datadog.trace.agent.common.writer
                .TraceProcessingWorker$DaemonTraceSerializingHandler
                .runDutyCycle(TraceProcessingWorker.java : 155)
                    at datadog.trace.agent.common.writer
                .TraceProcessingWorker$DaemonTraceSerializingHandler
                .run(TraceProcessingWorker.java : 145)
                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java : 807)


You can see java.lang.Thread.State and thread_state as two different “perspectives” the JVM has over a thread state.

java.lang.Thread.State: is the thread status from the application's perspective, simply put an enum that displays the current thread’ status at a high level (NEW, BLOCKED, TERMINATED, …)
thread_state: the low-level thread state used internally by the JVM. It provides a more granular view of what the thread is doing at the JVM level

EDIT: to clarify, by high level I mean that java.lang.Thread.State is a state of JVM thread state machine which do not reflect any operating system thread states, as pointed out in the comments.

so whats the actual state of the thread right now blocked or timed waiting ??

The thread is blocked.
java.lang.Thread.State gives you more information about the current state by saying that the thread is TIMED_WAITING (parked and waiting for a condition to be met).

It seems rather that java.lang.Thread.State is the state of the JVM thread "state machine" as defined in the Java API (in this case, the state is TIMED_WAITING), whereas _thread_blocked is ... whatever the thread state is that the underlying operating system uses, said thread state being mapped to one of the API states.
